# Angularjs: Find all instances of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive to allow the user to navigate the page with arrow keys by section. But I also want to be able to have those sections be scattered around the dom, and to have this not break when stuff gets added and removed. I can think of several ways to do this, but none of them are satisfactory:

- Create a directive with a controller that lets other directives register themselves (and unregister on $destroy). But this will be out of order if I add something in the middle later. Also, I've tried writing it this way, and it seems like way more code than necessary.
- Whenever the user hits an arrow key, make an empty array, and $broadcast an event, with a callback for directives to register themselves on that list. Then, once that list is full, advance or go backwards on it. They (should?) come back in the order they're in on the DOM, but I'm not sure since this way seems crazy and hackish.
- Mark things that are 'tabbable' with css, and write this the simple way in jquery, something like this: On a new click event, `var all = $('.tabbable')`, and then do the obvious with that. But I really don't want to do it that way, because it's not 'the angular' way. Not out of some sense of purity, but because I'm building this as part of a larger library of widgets, and I want this functionality to be accessibly to them.

So, is there any way for me to get the scopes of all directives of a certain type, without resorting to weird hacks, or spreading the logic out all over the place?

Answer (score 5):

This is a good question. +1

First, finding all directives or nodes by type goes against the Angular way. The View is the official record in AngularJS, so directives should say what they do and do what they say. Coding some process somewhere to scan for DOM nodes and act accordingly is problematic for several reasons, not the least of which are separation of concerns and testability.

I'm glad to see you're looking at other options, but I agree that the other options you provided are sub-optimal for the very reasons you mentioned. But I have one more. This is one that I've used for a different application, but that required knowledge of scattered DOM nodes.

First, we create a service to manage the state of this component. It's simple. Let's call it `SectionsService`. Next, we create a directive to register sections. Let's call that `section` for simplicity. The `section` directive registers the DOM node's ID (maybe created programmatically to ensure uniqueness) with the `SectionsService` during its linking phase. Since the DOM is processed (mostly) in order, the nodes added to the `SectionsService` will also be in order. So the DOM looks something like this (irrelevant stuff omitted):

```html
<div section>...</div>

<!-- other stuff -->

<div section>...</div>

<!-- other stuff -->

<!-- etc. -->
```

(Though out of scope here, it would not be very difficult to program it in such a way that the order wouldn't matter, but it'd be based on specifics of your app that I don't know.)

Next, you create your triggers, like an arrow key handler. On these events, you simply tell the `SectionService` to go to the previous/next node in the list. AngularJS comes with a service called [`$anchorScroll`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$anchorScroll) that can be used to emulate the browser's hash-based positioning we're familiar with. You could obviously also use a jQuery plugin to animate the scrolling if you wanted to.

And that's it! A very simply directive, a fairly simple service, and whatever trigger(s) you need. All told, I'd guess less than 100 lines of code including tests. All components are decoupled and easily testable, but still really quite simple. The view remains The Truth. The Angular Way is preserved.

And there was much rejoicing.

---

I hope this sets you on the right direction, but of course feel free to ask a follow-up question. We can also talk code specifics too if you'd like; as I said, they wouldn't be very complicated.

Comment: I agree that a service is a good solution, but how would I get it's list of tabbable things in an order that reflects the dom, as they are added and removed arbitrarily? (if an array of tabbable things gets sorted or shuffled, I want their tab order to reflect their order on the page.) I'm currently back to the 'broadcast a callback' on each navigation action, to get them in the order I need, and it's working quite well. (I had mistakenly though that $broadcast was async, which would have made that solution a lot yuckier)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the broadcast. Any component or directive can communicate with the `SectionService`, so it shouldn't be any problem notifying it of changes.

Answer (score 2):

[AngularJS services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) are singletons and can be required via dependency injection.  You could have your directives require a state manager service and call incrementers/decrementers.

Alternatively, a little easier but more brittle, you could keep an array in $rootScope.  It's more idiomatic "angular" (but not by much) than a jquery selector global, but probably not the best route if you're building a widget library.

Comment: Any suggestions for handling the ordering of that array as they get shuffled around?

Comment: I think I'd need to understand the requirements a little better before I gave a suggestion.  Do you want the ordering hierarchical, chronological with respect to DOM insertion, etc. ?